# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Selenium-Eclipse while testing one Application

Tags: nosuchmethoderror

I am using Selenium 4. I am getting the below error while executing the script.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities.getBrowserVersion()'

I can provide code and POM if required. Please help if anyone has faced this in recent times.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded Selenium 4.8.1 and the same mapped using Build path under libraries. Then it's resolved.  I am using Chrome 110.0.5481.178[image]